# error installing jsonnet in python using pip install jsonnet

Tags: python, grafana, setup.py, jsonnet

I want to run libsonnet files for my Grafana dashboard. For that I want to install jsonnet as a python package to run my libsonnet files then.

FYI, I am using VScode on my windows 10 machine

```
pip install jsonnet
```

gives me the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\U765123\Downloads\grafonnet-lib-master> pip install jsonnet
Collecting jsonnet
  Using cached jsonnet-0.19.1.tar.gz (593 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: jsonnet
  DEPRECATION: jsonnet is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for jsonnet ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for jsonnet did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is 
deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> jsonnet

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Would be glad if someone could help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but on a completely different platform (mac w/homebrew), and the problem/solution was **updating the underlying tools**, i.e. removing conflicting versions of python and updating xcode (which gives the mac basic toolchains, like `make` and `gcc`).